# One scroll bar in two text boxes but in custom tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, scrollbar, customtkinter

I am trying to create a typing speed calculator in customtkinter and I have acomplished some things too but i am stuck at a point. The problem is that i have created two text boxes one will show the text the user have to type and second in which user type to practice the programme check if the text is right or wrong and highlight the text according to it in green and red colour. This is what all i have done now the problem is when the user reaches the end of the text box the text box in which the user type scrolls but not the other one and the user is unable to see the next text. Try to run this code for better understanding.

I didn't tried anything but i had a idea to attach the scrollbar that the text box have as default to both of the text boxes but i am unable to implement it as i do not have access to the scrollbars attached to them by default

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.